# Problema with SQL delete in Aruba server

Tags: php, sql, aruba

I built a website to contain a library catalog. Each book can be edited and deleted. The elimination takes place through normal SQL delete and in localhost it works perfectly. It doesn't work on the Aruba server. I click the button and it does nothing. The code is the exact same. Create and modify any books are all goods, only deleting make problems. There is something I don't know. Can you help me?

In my opinion there is a problem with the php and SQL permissions on the Aruba server but not knowing how to get my hands on it I'm stuck. Can you help me?

Comment: Are you getting any error when you attempt a deletion?

Comment: Are you logging any exceptions/errors that are generated by the `DELETE` statement execution in PHP?

Comment: And, I am guessing you are using Aruba DBaaS. I am not familiar with how it is managed, but according to [their site](https://kb.arubacloud.com/en/database/cloud-dbaas/faq.aspx), you should be able to connection using MS SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Yes, when I try to delete a book the console gives me a 404 error. But it's not possible since the files are the same as the localhost. I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in the localhost I called the getUser.php page with a small "u". I don't understand why in the JS file where I call the php page it is not case sensitive and instead on the Aruba server it is... in any case the problem was that.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.

Comment: JS just calls whatever URL you give it...case sensitive doesn't come into it at that point. But when you get to the server...well some operating systems and webservers are case sensitive, and some aren't. Maybe your server is a different environment than your local machine.